# Open interactive SSH session from Node script

Tags: node.js, bash, unix, ssh

I am currently working on rebuilding our internal CLI tools as a command-line Node application. Part of this involves rebuilding the bash script to SSH into a specific server part of this app.

I know how to use `child_process`'s `spawn` function to actually execute SSH, but this does not yield the same result as just SSH'ing in the shell directly (even when using flag `-tt` on the `ssh` command). For one, typed commands are shown on the screen twice and trying to use `nano` on these remote machines does not work at all (screen size is incorrect, only takes up about half of the console window, and using arrows does not work).

Is there a better way to do this in a node app? This is the general code I currently use to start the SSH session:

```
run: function(cmd, args, output) {
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
        ls = spawn(cmd, args);

    ls.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
    });

    ls.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
        output.err(data.toString());
    });

    ls.on('exit', function(code) {
        process.exit(code);
    });

    process.stdin.resume();
    process.stdin.on('data', function(chunk) {
        ls.stdin.write(chunk);
    });

    process.on('SIGINT', function() {
        process.exit(0);
    });
}
```

Comment: I made a module for that [ssh2-client](https://github.com/MatthieuLemoine/ssh2-client)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [ssh2-client](https://github.com/MatthieuLemoine/ssh2-client) package

```
const ssh = require('ssh2-client');

const HOST = 'junk@localhost';

// Exec commands on remote host over ssh
ssh
  .exec(HOST, 'touch junk')
  .then(() => ssh.exec(HOST, 'ls -l junk'))
  .then((output) => {
    const { out, error } = output;
    console.log(out);
    console.error(error);
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

// Setup a live shell on remote host
ssh
  .shell(HOST)
  .then(() => console.log('Done'))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

DISCLAIMER : I'm the author of this module